# How to find the Sass file for a particular HTML page in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

As per the ionic tutorial [Ionic Framework Tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-background)

The styles should be added in the Sass file for the page.
I am unable to find the Sass file for the HTML pages in the template folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create a new page you need at least 2 files: a `.ts` file to define the page and its logic and an `.html` file to define what it show (otherwise called the *template*). If you want, you may also create a third `.scss` file wherin you can specify how the data defined in the template are styled.

All these 2 or 3 files are usually stored on the same folder for each page.

If you manually created a page (you created the .ts and html files) then just create another new .scss file in the same directory with them and with the same filename.

Alternatevely you can use the CLI to generate pages for you automatically by typing in the terminal:

`ionic generate page MyNewPage`

or its shorthand which also works (handy if you use it a lot)

`ionic g p MyNewPage`